# PC in reboot loop, even after replacing most components (processor failed?)

Tags: cpu, motherboard, power-supply, intel-core-i5, components

Out of the blue my PC started going into a reboot loop whenever turned on.

I checked every component, replaced the RAM, took the GPU out, took the HDD out, reset the mobo CMOS, and replaced the new motherboard and power supply. Even with nearly everything replaced but the CPU, it still goes into a reboot loop. Does this mean my CPU ([i5-6400](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/88185/intel-core-i5-6400-processor-6m-cache-up-to-3-30-ghz.html)) ([datasheet](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/docs/processors/core/desktop-6th-gen-core-family-datasheet-vol-1.html)) has failed? How common is that sort of thing? My CPU is about 3 years old. What else could be causing this issue?

My OS is debian netrunner, but I also tried it with a windows HDD. It doesn't seem to matter if there is a hard drive connected.

EDIT: It was the processor.

Comment: Its a possibility...  This is not a question anyone can answer over the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't find a MTBF (Mean Time Between Failure) figure for that component, but it certainly can fail. Since those CPUs typically have a three year warranty, I would visit the Intel Warranty web page and fill out their [warranty form](https://supporttickets.intel.com/warrantyinfo?lang=en-US).